# How to iterate a list of objects using logic:iterate and display each object property values in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, struts, loops

I have a list of objects (Java beans) assigned to a session attribute in my action class as follows:

```
List<NewProfile> profiles = ... ;
session.setAttribute("profiles", profiles);
```

This `profiles` is a list of objects of a class named `NewProfile`.

Now I have to retrieve the profiles and iterate through each `NewProfile` instance and print the values of their attributes/properties as a table using `logic:iterate`.

Suggestions are welcome! Thanks in advance!

Regards
Vijay

Answer (score 2):

May be this sample could help [logic:iterate](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-logic-iterate-example/)

Comment: Yup! it worked...that was a property mismatch error for me..any how thanks... But i have 1 more doubt.. In the same jsp How to retrieve lists when i have two lists each specifying a particular object...

Comment: Also im getting these retrieved records in a single page..is there any idea to show the results using pagination? help pls...

Comment: That's a bit more complex. The typical approach to pagination is to have a uniform means of sorting your results in your backend code, and only providing the page with a subsection of the full result set, based on a page number argument in the request and a results-per-page count.